# Unsure where to fine this error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.3

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':upkeepsp:processDebugResources'.
 > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
```

The above error occurred in Android Studio after I separated what was originally 1 module into 3 different modules.

I uninstalled and reinstalled android studio and imported the project into the new version and received this same error.

I have looked on other threads with similar issues yet I have not found the exception I received in any of the other examples.If I just knew where I may be able to find it in android studio I believe I could better search online where to solve it. Lastly when I click the error it does not take me anywhere.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the stacktrace in logcat?

Comment: Windows or Ubuntu? (or something exotic?)